# Doubt in thermodynamics pressure volume work done

Tags: thermodynamics, work, reversibility

Why work done in irreversible process is not calculated as -$\int p_{internal} dV$ ?

Comment: How would you calculate $p_{int}$ for a gas that is experiencing an irreversible process and is not at thermodynamic equilibrium?

Comment: by pv = nrt  i think

Comment: That equation applies only to an ideal gas at thermodynamic equilibrium.  In an irreversible process, the gas is not at thermodynamic equilibrium, and the pressure also depends on how fast the volume is changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you mean by “pressure int” is the internal pressure of the gas, then the reason is for an irreversible expansion or compression process, the gas is not thermally or mechanically in equilibrium. There are pressure gradients within the gas so there is no single defined internal equilibrium pressure as there is if the process were reversible.

Therefore, the work must therefore be calculated on the basis of the externally applied pressure, or the integral of

$$\int P_{external}dV$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: why we cannot put in place of p int  . p = nrt  and calculate like for instance in isthermal reversible  process work eq  should be equal to reversible isothermal as pv = nrt is valid for both and i also assume plank to be massless

Comment: pv=nrT is the equation of state for an ideal gas in equilibrium. As I said, during an irreversible (non quasi static) process the ideal gas not in equilibrium, so the equation pv=nrT does not apply. Hope that helps.